# Angular $scope not working inside modal window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, modal-dialog

I'm following [this guide](http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/12/09/authentication-made-simple-in-single-page-angularjs-applications.html) to implement authentication into my Angular app and I'm having trouble accessing models inside my controller.

Somewhere in my app, I open the modal window like this:

```
loginModal().then(function() {
    // Successful login, proceed to the page the user wants
    return $state.go(toState.name, toParams);
}).catch(function() {
    // Login failed, return home
    return $state.go('home');
});
```

`loginModal()` is a service, which looks like this:

```
myApp.service('loginModal', function($modal, $localStorage) {
    function assignCurrentUser(user) {
        $localStorage.user = user;
        return user;
    }

    return function() {
        var instance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/partials/modals/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginController',
            windowClass: 'small'
        });

        return instance.result.then(assignCurrentUser);
    };
});
```

When the `loginModal()` service is used, it opens a modal window on the page which contains the HTML of the `/partials/modals/login.html` file. This all works perfectly. You'll notice that I'm also specifying the controller to use in the modal: `LoginController`.

The `LoginController` is written as so:

```
myApp.controller('LoginController', function($scope) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        console.log($scope.user);
    };
});
```

and, finally, the partial which is used in the modal window:

```
<form name="loginForm" novalidate method="post" ng-submit="login();">
    <label>Email address
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="user.email">
    </label>
    <label>Password
        <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="user.password">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

The issue is that when I fill out the form (by populating `user.email` and `user.password`) and click the submit button, I get `undefined` printed to the console.

Basically, the `$scope.login` function from my `LoginController` does get executed, but the `$scope.user` property is undefined even though it should be populated by the form in the modal window (with the use of `ng-model`s).

Also, if I put `{{user.email}}` into the modal template and then populate the email field, it does get printed. So I know that two-way data binding works.

Why can't I access the `$scope` values from a modal window inside my controller?

Comment: does this issue resolved or you still need any thing?

Answer (score 0):

Don't now if it help, but I had such problem with routing.
The solution was to use `ng-model="$parent.user.name"` add `$parent` to dependencies list in controller, and call it using `$scope.$parent.user.email`
or just `$scope.user.email`sometimes it works.
Hope helped you.

Comment: Nope, none of that worked :( Although I think you might've nudged me in the right direction to figure this out!